# Setting a frame id

Tags: ros, laser-assembler

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem in setting a `world` frame id. I did as below, but it doesn't work. It that right what I did and where should it actually be set? I've also tried with and without (/), but, it makes no difference at the moment. The error that I suspect is, in the fixed_frame in rviz I couldn't tick for it. What more I have the following warning:

```
[ WARN] [1329404542.223645698]: Warning: Frame id /world does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
```

Code snippet:

```
    void AssemblerClient::useAssembler(const sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr& scan_ptr)
    {
      ROS_INFO("Assembler service is being used");

      ros::service::waitForService("assemble_scans");
      ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<AssembleScans>("assemble_scans");
      AssembleScans srv;
      srv.request.begin = ros::Time(0,0);
      srv.request.end   = ros::Time::now();
      if (client.call(srv))
      {
        ROS_INFO("Got cloud with %u points\n", srv.response.cloud.points.size());

        gathered_cloud = srv.response.cloud;
        gathered_cloud.header.frame_id = "/world";

        gathered_cloud_publisher_.publish(gathered_cloud);
      }
        else
        ROS_INFO("Service call failed\n");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27772/setting-a-frame-id/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like something needs to define a transform from `/world` to `/base_link`.

[REP-0105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) explains the usual coordinate conventions for mobile robots.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3